# Recording the alpha channel > Unity Recorder but with built-in pipeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, alpha, recording, unity-timeline

There are some topics in the unity forum about how to record image sequences or whole videos with alpha channel with the Unity Recorder. HDRP & URP has this feature working, as it seems. But I don't see any experiences or tips regarding the built-in pipeline. My project is too big & complex to switch to the other pipelines. What I ask myself the whole time is, is the built-in pipeline even capable of recording the alpha channel, with the fact that it is not maintained for a long time now?

Can someone tell me if it works, or if there is a workaround? The Unity plugin OFFLINE RENDER seems not to support alpha channel, but depth, this and that ^^ but no alpha channel O_O

I can't remember now what everything I already tried. :/

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Unity Recorder with a built-in render pipeline project and the alpha channel is coming out fine.

Set the camera clear flag to Solid Color, with alpha 0.
In Unity Recorder I'm using an Image Sequence with PNG and 'Include Alpha' set.

I noticed Post-processing Depth of Field effect breaks the alpha channel render.

What is your set up? (I would comment the question but I don't have the rep)